# @MOCK in Junit 5 returns NULL when using @Value in constructor

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5, fileinputstream

I am writing test cases for a project which uses File inpurstream at multiple places. Due to the issues with PowerMock and Junit5, I ended up using a Constructor with @Value to pass file paths to the class. Sample code will show.

Now When I use the constructor with @Value. The test cases for File inputStream work perfectly. But @MOck for any other class returns NULL. 
I comment the constructor and @Mock starts working.

any One faced this before?

Class to be tested:

```
@Component
public class test {


    TestUtils testUtil;

    String nodeConfigFilePath;
    String genConfigFilePath;

    public test (@Value("${node.config.path}") String nodeConfigFilePath, 
            @Value("${genConfig.path}", @Autowired TestUtils testUtil) String genConfigFilePath) {
        this.nodeConfigFilePath=nodeConfigFilePath;
        this.genConfigFilePath= genConfigFilePath;
        this.testUtil = testUtil;
    }



    public boolean filterConfig(JSONObject Json) {
                if(testUtil.iterateJsonForPatternMatch(Json))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        public void loadConfigFromJson() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<Map<String, String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
        };
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(nodeConfigFilePath);
            Map<String, String> nodeConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
            nodeConfig = mapper.readValue(inputStream,typeRef);
            <do something>
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }


}
```

Test Class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class test {

    @InjectMocks
    test test;

    @Mock
    TestUtils testUtil;

    @Test
    public void testFilterConfig_success() throws Exception{
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        when(testUtil.iterateJsonForPatternMatch(jsonObj)).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(true, test.filterConfig(jsonObj));

    }
    @Test
       public void testloadConfigFromJson_success() throws Exception{
         test = new NotificationFilter(nodeConfigFile.getAbsolutePath(),genConfigJsonFile.getAbsolutePath(), testUtil);
        test.loadConfigFromJson();
    }

}
```

FYI: I changed the method names and created a dummy class for demo purpose.

So If Now I remove the @Value constructor, It starts working and no Null pointer for **testUtil**. But testloadConfigFromJson_success() starts to fail. And Vice versa. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

UPDATE: moved autoiring to constructor and passed the TestUtil instance via constructor in Test class. It seems to do the trick. I am not sure if its correct

Comment: I think your `@Mock` / `@InjectMocks` variables are wrong. They should be the other way around? .... Because TestUtils should be the mock and should be injected in test or??

Comment: Do yourself many favors. 1. respect tha Java naming conventions. 2. Stop using field injection: everything that needs to be injected, including your TestUtils dependency, inject it via the constructor. 3. You don't need Mock, InjectMocks and MockitoExtension anymore: all you need is to create a mock TestUtil and two strings, and to call the constructor with these 3 arguments in your test.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 RunWith is for JUnit 4, and Mock and InjectMocks are places on the right variables here.

Comment: yes sorry your are right.... dont post before first coffee :D

Comment: @JBNizet : Thanks for the response.
1) These are dummy classes for reference not the actual code facing issue.  for the 3rd point, do you mean I create a constructor and inject TestUtil from there into Test because I am using Autowired to inject bean where needed in Test class.

Comment: Also my confusiion is why its happening in the first place? Mock is not working right If I use Value in constructor

Comment: You use constructor injection for the String dependencies, and field injection for the testUtil dependency. If you let Mockito construct the object and and inject the TestUtil, then the Strings will be null. If you construct the Test yourself using the constructor, then the TestUtil field will stay null. I stand by my previous comment: make the dependencie clear and explicit by using constructor injection for all the dependencies (the String and the TestUtil). Then call the constructor yourself with all the necessary arguments.

Comment: @JBNizet: So I am not sure what I did is as what you expected. Can you check the edited code above? I moved the autowiring to constructor, I did not want to let go of autowiring concept . 
But I am doubtful is its ok to write code like this. autowiring in a constructor I mean. Let me know if you meant something else. Its working but.

Comment: It is OK, But the Autowired should be on the constructor itself. And if that's the only constructor it's not even required by Spring.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, its the only constructor so I did not autowire that.